# Mongoose 'pre(save)' hook interfering with save() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I am working on the authentication logic for this e-commerce project.
I am using mongoose and validator to verify some fields in my userSchema.
I also have a 'pre('save') that hashes user password before persisting to the database.
I have a endpoint for email verification, that updates few fields in the userSchema,the password field is not among the fields this email verification endpoint updates but I keep getting this error when I fire this email verification endpoint.
Here are some codes for clarity:
UserSchema file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true,'Please tell us your name']
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email']
  },

  phone: {
    type: String,
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false
  },

  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      // This only works on CREATE and SAVE!!!
      validator: function(el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords are not the same!'
    }
  },

  isVerified: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },

  token: String
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  if(!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  next();

  // Delete PasswordConfirm field
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
});

// Instance methods
// Available on all documents in this collection
userSchema.methods.confirmPassword = async function
(enteredPassword, dbPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, dbPassword);
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Here is the email verification file:

```
exports.confirmEmail = async (req, res) => { 

const token = req.query.token;
console.log('This is the token: ', token); 
try { 
const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
console.log('This is Decoded: ', decoded);

const user = await User.findOne({ email: decoded.payload.email });
console.log('This is the user: ', user);

// Checking if the token is still valid
if(decoded.exp * 1000 < Date.now() || !user){ 
console.log('Token is expired');
res.status(401).send('Token has expired'); return;
 };
user.token = undefined;
user.isVerified = true;
await user.save();

console.log('Email verified');
return res.status(200).json({ 
status: 'success', 
message: 'Email verified' }) }
catch (error) {
console.log(error.message);
res.status(500).json({ status:'failed', message: error.message }) } }
```

And this is the error I keep getting

```
User validation failed: passwordConfirm: Please confirm your password
```

I eventually used findOneAndUpdate() to get around this issue, but I'd really like to know what's actually going on and why that error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to save some data using `save()` but don't want to trigger the validators
you have to set this option `await Your_Model.save({ validateBeforeSave: false});` which is `true` by default, updating the data doesn't trigger the schema's validators that's why you could run your confirm email md without problems.

I don't know if my answer is what you wanted but still hope it can help someone.